# xtable() changes hms output to number when printing in HTML

Tags: html, r, time, format, xtable

When using `xtable()` to print a data frame into HTML email body the output changes to numeric instead of the original format on the data frame which is set `as.hms()`

The original observation is numeric: `79` and the below code converts the average to `as.hms()` format `00:01:19`

```
Avg_Answer_Time <- transport %>%
  filter(Call_Type == "Inbound customer") %>% 
  summarise(as.hms(round(mean(TimeInQueue))))
```

And then run the below code for the data frame to HTML the output goes back to numeric on the email: `79`

```
InboundSummary <- print(xtable(Inbound_Summary, digits = 0), type="html", print.results=FALSE, )
InboundBody <- paste0("<html>", InboundSummary, "</html>")
```

Is there any way to print as the original format (00:01:19) or have it to print the output as time format preferably minutes and seconds?

---

Example:

```
library(xtable)
library(hms)

seconds <- c(79,50,37)   
queue_secs <- as_hms(round(mean(seconds)))  
x <- data.frame(queue_secs) 
time_in_secs <- print(xtable(x), type="html", print.results=FALSE ) 
time_in_secs_body <- paste0("<html>", time_in_secs,"<html>")
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal reproducible example. See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Comment: Reproducible example:

`seconds <- c(79,50,37)  
queue_secs <- as.hms(round(mean(queue_secs)))  
x <- data.frame(queue_secs)
time_in_secs <- print(xtable(x), type="html", print.results=FALSE, )
time_in_secs_body <- paste0("<html>", time_in_secs,"<html>")`

Comment: I don't think it is anything to do with html but is `xtable` formatting -- you see the issue with `xtable(x)`. An easy fix is to convert to character: `x$queue_secs <- as.character(x$queue_secs); xtable(x)`